# Can PHP set it ini file at runtime?

Tags: php

Is there any method to change php's config when it's running? My business requirement is on FunctionA start turn up it's `max_execution_time` and on FunctionA finish turn down it.

Comment: why not use http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php ?

Comment: That's not possible.. However you could try [`ini_set()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)..

Comment: `max_execution_time` is changeable for [`PHP_INI_ALL`](http://php.net/manual/configuration.changes.modes.php) so yes, you can change it at runtime

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
<?php
    function functionA ()
    {
      if (!ini_get('max_execution_time') || ini_get('max_execution_time') != 3000)
      {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
      }
      // Do some things....
    }

    echo ini_get('max_execution_time'); // We return system default

    functionA ();

    echo ini_get('max_execution_time'); will return 3000
```

Beware that some host disable this ability. If thats the case and it is still needed you will need to contact your host to enable it or move hosting companies.